# Problem with SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] every time I launch my computer

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Every time I launch my computer when I type `php artisan serve` I get these commands..

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: select * from `sessions` where `id` = KsL5wVKGbNVEpBvHCDrEr8Q8eoZWA3ja2KGejyvZ limit 1)
```

I know the solution to my problem which is typing the problem:

1. `sudo chown -R _mysql:mysql /usr/local/var/mysql`
2. `sudo mysql.server start`

I want it to persist. I don't want this problem to show agoin

By the way, I am using:

- Mac, big Sure
- Mysql using brew
- Laravel 8

Comment: Try changing your DB_HOST in .env file to 127.0.0.1 with port number if any.

Comment: There are some possibilities for this case. For me, the db server is not running yet.

Comment: It is not the problem, the problem is I want MySQL to open on startup

Answer (score 0):

After searching in multiuple places I found the solution:

- reset `brew` permission
- then type this command: `sudo brew services start mysql`

that's it.